# How to Use ORDERBY in the flexible serach query (UNION)

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

I am trying to create flexible search query as below :

```
SELECT uniontable.PK FROM
(
   {{
      SELECT {p1:PK} AS PK FROM {Product AS p1},{Product AS p2} 
      WHERE {p1.code} = {p2.Att1}
   }}
   UNION ALL
   {{
      SELECT {p:PK} AS PK FROM {Product AS p}
      WHERE {p1.Att1} is not empty
   }}
) uniontable
```

Can anyone tell mehow to use "ORDER BY " creation time of product  keyword in above query?

Comment: Why is MySQL tagged here?

Comment: I don't understand your query fully but try this `SELECT uniontable.PK FROM
(
   {{
      SELECT {p1:PK} AS PK, {p1:creationtime} AS creationtime FROM {Product AS p1},{Product AS p2} 
      WHERE {p1.code} = {p2.Att1}
   }}
   UNION ALL
   {{
      SELECT {p:PK} AS PK, {p:creationtime} AS creationtime FROM {Product AS p}
      WHERE {p.Att1} is not empty
   }}
) as uniontable
ORDER BY uniontable.creationtime`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it's more simple :

```
 SELECT {p1:PK} AS PK FROM {Product AS p1},{Product AS p2} WHERE {p1.code} = {p2.Att1} AND {p1.Att1} is not empty ORDER BY {p1.creationtime}
```

Hope this helps